# Специализация метода шаблона класса С++

Tags: c++, методы, шаблоны-с++

У меня есть шаблон класса. Я захотел добавить метод, но только для одного конкретного типа. При использовании частичной специализации, по сути, нужно переписывать все поля и методы, даже если я их не изменяю. В итоге, при изменении чего-то общего, приходиться менять код в 2 местах.
Подскажите, есть ли какой-то другой способ реализации такого специального метода или как избежать такого неудобства?

UPD: С методом разобрался, спасибо. Но возникает вопрос, как тогда действовать, если нужно добавить атрибут?

Comment: Вы хотите добавить в специализацию метод, которого в принципе нет в общем шаблоне?

Comment: Проиллюстрируйте или детальнее опишите проблему. В тексте вопроса вы пишете про *добавление* метода, а в заголовке речь идет о *специализации* метода. Навскидку, это несовместимые понятия - нельзя специализировать то, чего еще нет. Поясните, о чем вы ведете речь.

Answer (score 6):

Если у вас есть шаблон класса, то его методы являются независимыми шаблонами и специализировать их можно независимо. Т.е. для этого не надо специализировать весь класс заново

```
template <typename T> struct Class
{
   int i;

   void foo()
   {
      i = 5;
      std::cout << "Generic implementation" << std::endl;
   }
};

template <> void Class<int>::foo()
{
  i = 42;
  std::cout << "Specialized implementation" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  Class<double> d;
  d.foo();
  std::cout << d.i << std::endl;

  Class<int> i;
  i.foo();
  std::cout << i.i << std::endl;
}
```

Однако *добавить* метод, которого изначального нет в основном шаблоне таким способом не получится. Если вам нужно именно *добавить* метод, то возможно имеет смысл объявить этот метод в главном шаблоне (не определяя его, или определив его как deleted), а потом уже предоставлять специализации вышеописанным способом.

Comment: Если добавить (не определяя) метод в основной шаблон, нельзя будет создать экземпляр класса с другим шаблонным параметром.

Comment: @andy.37: Не верно. Экземпляр класса можно будет создать. Нельзя будет *вызвать* этот метод для классов с другим шаблонным параметром. А это именно то, что нам и надо.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Что как-то странно, имхо.

Comment: Кстати, если объявить метод `virtual`, то не скомпилируется, даже без попытки вызова, что впрочем тоже понятно.

Comment: @andy.37: Как я сказал выше, шаблон самого класса и шаблоны его методов - это *независимые* шаблоны. Они специализируются и инстанциируются *независимо*. Это важное фундаментальное свойство С++ шаблонов. Благодаря этому свойству, например, мы можем использовать `std::vector<T>` с типом `T`, не имеющим default-конструктора. И это будет работать прекрасно, пока мы не используем методы `std::vector`, полагающиеся на наличие default-конструктора.

Comment: `virtual` - это совсем другая история. Виртуальные методы шаблонных классов всегда инстанциируются безусловно (по понятным причинам), в отличие от обычных методов.

Comment: Думаю так можно специализировать метод шаблона, но вот частичная специализация только одного из методов шаблона уже работать не будет.

Comment: @23W: Не понял, о чем вы ведете речь. В С++ частичная специализация (partial specialization) поддерживается только для шаблонов классов. Но о partial specialization здесь речи вообще не идет. К чему вы ее упомянули?

Comment: @AnT вы правы, я невнимательно прочитал ответ, думал он затрагивает и частичную специализацию.

Answer (score 2):

GCC компилирует следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct A
{
    A(T x) : x(x) {}
    void foo() = delete; // { cout << "default: " << x << endl; }
    void bar() { cout << "bar: " << x << endl; }

    T x;
};

template<>
void A<int>::foo()
{
    cout << "int: " << x << endl;
}


int main()
{
    A<int> a(0);
    a.foo();
    a.bar();

    A<double> b(0);
    // b.foo(); // - не компилируется
    b.bar();

    A<string> c("hello");
    // c.foo(); // - не компилируется
    c.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Собственно, если заменить `= delete`, на закомментированный код, все будет работать, как в ответе AnT.